# Why are some elements in IE8 acting responsive?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I have a responsive site that I'm building that needs to work in IE8+ as well as modern browsers. IE8 isn't a responsive browser but some elements are responding to screen width. Is there a known issue that causes elements to respond this way?

Could the fact that my framework is percentage based instead of px based?

Comment: IE8 still obeys percentage based units. In my responsive websites, I detect IE8 and I set a min-width on the body of 990px - this forces a horizontal scrollbar below that width in IE8 and your percentage based items will also stop expanding/collapsing below this width.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries will not work in IE, but percentage width will (in many cases).

Generally I solve this by including a conditional ie.css file and setting a fixed width for the containing element.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```